# Category-SubCategory dropdown in django

Tags: python, django

I need to show a sub-Category depending on the type of category that has been shown.
Some thing like this

```
Group 1
   ==>Group1_subcat1
   ==>Group1_subcat2

Group 2
   ==>Group2_subcat1
   ==>Group2_subcat2
```

**Models**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=64)
    group=models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

**Forms**

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    '''Creates a form for the application to add a contact. '''
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all())
    category=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(group=group.id))//error is here
```

**html**

```
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you want to show a single dropdown or you want the user to select a group in a dropdown and have the other one populated according to that choice?

Comment: Categories must come according to group selected.

Comment: Maybe something like that http://dealingit.wordpress.com/2009/10/26/django-tip-showing-optgroup-in-a-modelform/

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to be of help, but [here](https://gist.github.com/asermax/6418178) is a messy implementation of something among the lines of what you need. I made that some time ago for a project, so it may not be as flexible since it wasn't thought with reusability on mind. Also the comments are in spanish because it's my main language d:. Anyway, feel free to use it if it fits your needs and drop a comment if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat hacky approach using jQuery, I'm sure there is a better way but it might give you some ideas.  I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for so it does not match your model exactly.  Type might be your Category field and then I'm populating the Category field with subcategories.  Subcats can be one of two lists depending on the setting of Type.

In the template display the form field:

```
  Type  {{form.org_type}}
  Category {{form.category}}
```

Then added some javascript to the template:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    // subcatlist1 and subcatlist2 are querysets passed to the template.
    var subcat_1 = ' {% for subcat in subcatlist1 %}<option value="{{subcat.id}}">{{subcat.name}}</option> {% endfor %}';

    var subcat_2 = ' {% for subcat in subcatlist2 %}<option value="{{subcat.id}}">{{subcat.name}}</option> {% endfor %}';


    // initialise subcat choices based on type 
    subcat_choices();

    // if the type field is changed, change the subcategory list
    $('#id_org_type').change(function() {
        subcat_choices();

    });

    function subcat_choices() {
        // change the content of the category dropdown to hold a list of subcategories
        if ($("#id_org_type option:selected").val() == '1') {
            $("#id_category").html(subcat_1);
        } else {
            $("#id_category").html(subcat_2);
        }
    }

  });
</script>
```